# Private repository collaborators and issue tracking

Tags: github, repository, issue-tracking

There are basically two questions I have. Recently, I upgraded my GitHub account.

Now, two other users also want to access the repository. I can add them as a collaborator (by going to `settings/collaboration` page) onto my repository but: **If they fork the project, will it be public or private? They do not have a paid GitHub account.**

I think the above can be easily remedied by testing this first. My second problem is: The project source is private; but it is still shown to a wide audience whom I want to give access to a issue-tracker or a bug-report feature. Currently, I just have created a basic web form where they are filing the bugs as text and I'm storing them into MySQL database.

**Is there any way to allow access to *issues' tracker* for the private project so that it is available to public**? As a *workaround*, I can create an empty repository for the issues and provide it to the public, but I wouldn't want to work upon it if their is an easy solution to it.

Comment: Github has very friendly help staff who can help with this.

Comment: @Abizern In regards to the first question or the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If they fork the project, will it be public or private? They do not have a paid GitHub account.

No, forking a private repository keeps it private, even if the person who forked it has a free account and cannot make private repositories. We do this at work - the company has a paid account, and each developer uses their own (sometimes free) account.

> Is there any way to allow access to issues tracker for the private project so that it is available to public?

Not that I'm aware of. It is the repository that is public/private, not specific elements of it. GitHub themselves [recommend creating a second repository](https://help.github.com/articles/issues-only-access-permissions) for the issue tracker.

Comment: hmm, I swear that article never appeared when I was searching at https://help.github.com/